# How to implement a toy DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystallography

I want to learn DFT for research purposes and I need to implement a toy DFT for pedagogical reasons.
I would like some recommendations regarding resources like books, articles, or any other thing that will help in this matter.

Comment: Do you want to implement periodic calculations, molecular calculations, or both?

Comment: @wzkchem5 for both

Comment: If you want to write a whole program you should probably start from some existing integral code - espicially if you are doing molecular calculations. Writing integral code is not particulary easy.

Comment: If you are looking for some toy model with play with DFT, there's something called the Hookean atom problem. See:  https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1559914 and for time dynamics there's some work with single slater determinants see: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.85.054501

Comment: If there's more interest I'd be happy to add a more detailed answer, the question as such is too broad.

Comment: this is more or less a duplicate of https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/how-to-write-my-own-density-functional-theory-dft-code-in-python. The top answer is a pretty good one. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1057/3606

Comment: I would tend to agree that its a duplicate of the question Wesley linked. Does that address your question @sinecosine? If not, please edit your post to explain what specifically isn't addressed by the linked post. I can reopen the post if you there is something missing from the other post.